# Is there any summary which describes "real-life" applications of various data structures?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Practical uses of different data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539069/practical-uses-of-different-data-structures)

Could please anyone point me out to a brief summary which describes `real-life` applications of various data structures? I am looking for ready-to-use summary not a reference to the Cormen's book :)

For example, almost every article says what a Binary tree is; but they doesn't provide with  examples when they *really* should be used in real-life; the same for other data structures.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Data structures are so widely used that this summary will be actually enormous. The simplest cases are used almost every day -- hashmaps for easy searching of particular item. Linked lists -- for easy adding/removing elements(you can for example describe object's properties with linked lists and you can easily add or remove such properties). Priority queues -- used for many algorithms (Dijsktra's algorithm, Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning tree, Huffman's encoding). Trie for describing dictionary of words. Bloom filters for fast and cheap of memory search (your email's spam filter may use this). Data structures are all around us -- you really should study and understand them and then you can find application for them everywhere.