# Network Design: Why is Minimum Spanning Tree so widely used in Network Design

Tags: networking, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Recently I am really interested in Network Design. Right now I am reading about Minimum Spanning Tree. However I cannot find more than two reasons to use it:
- minimize total cost of cable used to connect all network utilities,
- minimize total latency.

Are there any more reasons to use it? What else can we minimize (optimize).

Thx in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

apart from network design and analysis, mst feature most prominently in following application domains:

- clustering ( statistics; specifically taxonomy, genetics, linguistics, machine learning )
- routing ( approximating shortest tours )
- sparse representations ( image recognition, handwriting analysis )

for more concrete sample applications consult google.

some arbitrary references:

1. [Murali](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs5114/spring2009/lectures/lecture08-mst-applications.pdf)
2. [g4g survey](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-of-minimum-spanning-tree/)
3. an application in [genetics](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/18/4/536)

and some related discussion on so:

- [Practical uses of different data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539069/practical-uses-of-different-data-structures)